# How to display images from server Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

My images successfully uploaded to the /myshop/uploads/ folder, but I difficult to load images to the browser.
This is my server-side code

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
            callBack(null, 'uploads')
            },
            filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
            callBack(null, Date.now() + '-'+ file.originalname)
            }
     })
    
    var upload = multer({storage: storage})
    
    
    
    //Upload image
    app.post('/api/myshop/photo', upload.single('file'),(req, res, next)=>{
    
    
            const file = req.file
            console.log(req.file.filename);
            if(!file){
            const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
            error.httpStatusCode = 400
            return next(error)
            }
    
            res.send(file)
    });
```

[image: Here my folder view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the file back to the client, you can use [sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.sendFile) method. You need to provide the file's path.

```
  //Upload image
    app.post('/api/myshop/photo', upload.single('file'),(req, res, next)=>{
    
            const file = req.file
            console.log(req.file.filename);
            if(!file){
              const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
              error.httpStatusCode = 400
              return next(error)
            }
    
            // send file back to client
            const filePath = req.file.path;
            res.sendFile(filePath);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the support, Using that I got the path of the image like this 'uploads/1621755676022-clipart2934035.png'. I try to load the image using "http://52.75.82.205:3000/myshop/uploads/1621755676022-clipart2934035.png" But that show "cannot get" error , Can you help

Comment: Have you configured express app to serve static files in "uploads" directory ? Something like this `app.use(express.static('uploads'))`. Then try `http://52.75.82.205:3000/1621755676022-clipart2934035.png`